# Prediction path for the ball getting hit by another ball

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm creating a pool game. What I need right now is a trajectory prediction path for the ball getting hit by another ball. When the ball is hit by the raycast of the main cue ball it will show it's trajectory path. I have created the raycast part what I need is a trajectory path for the ball(the green ball) getting hit by another ball(white ball)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't only need to calculate the direction. Consider that the path of the ball is not a line but has a radius. In fact, the point of impact of the ball is on the perimeter of the circle, so use a spherecast.

```
if (Physics.SphereCast(m_ball.transform.position, m_ball.radius, localDirection, out var hit, length, ballLayer.value))
{
    newDirection = hit.transform.position - hit.point;
}
```

Here I showed the difference between raycast and spherecast, which is the correct spherecast result due to the difference in their hit points.

[image]

Comment: can u show me a complete code?

Answer (score 0):

Raycast from the ball object you are hitting in a direction.
Let the ball game object be `myBall` which shall be shot in the direction `direction` and the direction of the ball that's going to be hit be `newDirection`.

```
if(Physics.Raycast(myBall.transform.position, direction, out RaycastHit hit))
{
    newDirection = hit.transform.position - hit.point;
}
```

Explaining the code a little bit, when an object collides with another object, it moves in the direction through its normal and the point at which the collision has happened.

Note: This only gives the direction of the ball that's hit, to know the velocity and other properties, the mass and velocity of the ball that's projected should be specified.